Is it correct for you (using a desk phone) to say "Please hold the line" when the person at the other end is using a smartphone?
There are some scenarios about Mary giving Jen a call.
Situation 1: Both used desk phones or phones using lines. Mary and Jen can say "Please hold the line".
Situation 2: Mary used a smartphone and Jen used a desk phone. or Mary used a desk phone and Jen used a smart phone.
Can Mary say to Jen "Please hold the line"?
Can Jen say to Mary "Please hold the line"?

It has been shortened to "Could you hold for a moment?"  "the line" is somewhat dated.  "Please hold the line" is something that might be said by someone who works the "switchboard" and routes calls internally.

We still sometimes use expressions relating to traditional telephones, like 'pick up' for answering a call and 'hang up' for ending one.

In general, Jen would not know if Mary was using a smartphone, Nokia brick, desk phone, or smart watch.  There's no way of knowing what technology the other person is using just from the sound of their voice.

Quite a lot of terminology connected with telephony is legacy. We still say "hang up" to mean terminate a call, even though we are no longer hanging a handset on a cradle. Automated phone systems say "please press" keys on your phone, even though most people will have a "touch" screen which is not technically depressed.
"The line" in the context of your example is understood to mean the connection and not a single line of cabling. Even before cellular phones you could make international calls which were routed via multiple 'lines', exchanges and satellites, but we'd probably still say "I can hardly hear you - it's a bad line!"
So, yes - it's absolutely fine to say "hold the line" no matter what phone you, or the other party is using. In some cases, a person may not even know what kind of telephone the other person is using, anyway.

It's not inappropriate; as Kate says, we still use phrases that relate to physical telephone technology like "hang up" even if we're not physically hanging a handset up, and indeed cellular phone service providers sometimes use the word "line" to talk about providing service, like "add an extra line to your account," even if the calls will go through radio waves instead of a physical line. (And I know little about telephone infrastructure; I'm sure the actual routing of even "land-line" calls these days involves a variety of technologies.)
But it would be more common to simply say "Please hold," perhaps with extra optional polite phrases. While the full "please hold the line" was certainly not unheard of in the early days of the telephone, as shown in this 1916 article on phone etiquette, it has become less common since switching became automated. It's hard to check Google ngrams, because using "please hold" as a query matches many unrelated things like "please hold [up your hand and be sworn in]." However, putting a period at the end of both phrases shows "please hold." rapidly overtaking "please hold the line." in use starting in the 1970s (though the sample size of this ngram might be quite small, so results should be taken with a grain of salt).
